# How to auto scale in JES

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, jython, jes

I'm coding watermarking images in JES and I was wondering how to Watermark a picture by automatically scaling a watermark image?

If anyone can help me that would be great.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ill start by giving you a quote from the INFT1004 assignment you are asking for help with.
**"In particular, you should try not to use code or algorithms from external sources, and not to obtain help from people other than your instructors, as this can prevent you from mastering these concepts"**
It specifically says in this assignment that you should not ask people online or use code you find or request online, and is a breach of the University of Newcastle academic integrity code - you know the thing you did a module on before you started the course. A copy of this post will be sent along to the course instructor.

Comment: Oh I see but I didn't receive any answers, no one replied nor given me an answer